# Function call works only for one time but doesn't work for next time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a function which consist of jQuery code to make the div resizable. the resizable functions work correctly for first time.but it doesn't work for second and next time. I added alert to that  function to check the call of function.Function calls but the resizable doesn't work.Why is that happening?And what is the solution? the code is here:

```
function rezDesc() {
    alert('resize');
    $(function () {
        $("#placeDescHere").resizable({
            ghost: true,
            alsoResize: '#LabelDesc',
            handles: " e, s"
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the inner function call out of its `$(function() { ... })` block.

```
function rezDesc() 
{
    alert('resizze');
    $("#placeDescHere" ).resizable({
        ghost: true,
        alsoResize:'#LabelDesc',
        handles: " e, s"
    });
}
```

Comment: If the DOM is already ready the function should be executed immediately so that's unlikely to break it.

Comment: but will it execute every time?

Comment: @Alnitak-If i use that $function outside the rezDesc() function then this functions is called when page loads.it acts like onLoad().. I dont want that..as per your suggestion i can do that without using the rezDesc() function also

Answer (score 1):

The inner function block is not required.

```
function rezDesc() 
{
    alert('resizze');
    $( "#placeDescHere" ).resizable({
        ghost: true,
        alsoResize:'#LabelDesc',
        handles: " e, s"
    }); 
}
```